# Java - Compare two strings - unicode/ascii sensitive

Tags: java

In java, is there a way to compare s1 = "\u0061" and s2 = "a" such that the comparison returns false?

Want unicode representation to be different from ascii letter.

Comment: Well, they aren't different, so there's no way for this to work.  Maybe you should keep track of the "representation"?  But that would require something other than a string.

Comment: What is the source of the strings? Do they come from some external source, or are they in the source code?

Comment: This is not a real application issue, I ran into it randomly while trying to learn more on representations and string comparisons. So, would really be curious how we handle both external source and source code cases. Thanks.

Comment: If you're writing those two things into a Java file, then `javac` will compile them to literally the same string. Not two strings that print the same way, but *literally* the exact same sequence of bytes. If you're getting literally a backslash followed by "u0061" from an external source, then the first step is to question the sanity of whoever sent that data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't a way.

Those two strings are the same.  Not just equal.  They will actually be represented at runtime by the same `String` object.

So a comparison will always tell you that those strings are equal.

---

> So, would really be curious how we handle both external source and source code cases.

It is "apples and oranges".

For the case of String literals, see above.

If you got the 6 characters `\u0061` in a text file, the standard Java I/O classes would not recognize that as a Unicode escape.  So the issue does not arise.

Likewise, if you constructed a Java `String` like this:

```
String s = "" + '\\' + 'u' + '0' + '0' + '6' + '1';
```

or similar, that is not recognized as a Unicode escape.  It is a 6 character string.

In short, `\uxxxx` is a notation not a representation.  It is used in Java source code only<sup>1</sup> to denote a character (code point).  Not in the runtime representation of strings.

And since `a` and `\u0061` denote the same character, they are indistinguishable.

---

<sup>1 - But not just in string and character literals.  You can also use Unicode escapes in identifiers and so on, though it is very bad for readability.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use escape sequence for unicode if you just want to represent without converting unicode value to character.

Below is the code if it helps :

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      String s1="\\u0061";
      String s2="a";
      System.out.println(s1);
      System.out.println(s2);
      System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
    }
}
```